# Copying tables results in duplication of some tables, feature classes and relationship classes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, table, relationship-class, copy

**ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3.**

I have a file geodatabase called "supportSource.gdb" with 3 tables, 2 feature classes and 3 relationship classes. I just want to copy the contents of this file geodatabase to another file geodatabase using python.  Fairly straightforward, or so I thought.

**Tables**

```
EnvGENvecAuditStreetSweeping__ATTACH
EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords
EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords__ATTACH
```

**FeatureClasses**

```
EnvGENvecAuditStreetSweeping
EnvvecTreeMaintenanceAreas
```

**Relationship Classes**

```
EnvGENvecAuditStreetSweeping__ATTACHREL
EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords__ATTACHREL
TreeMaintenance
```

[image]

If I try selecting all the tables and copying from the source geodatabase to a new empty geodatabase (called "dest.gdb" in Catalog, I get the following error:

[image]

Next, I tried a simple python script to copy the tables only into the destination geodatabase.

```
import os
from arcpy import env
destgdb = "E:\\Temp\\dest.gdb"
sourcegdb = "E:\\Temp\\supportSource.gdb"
env.workspace = sourcegdb
tableList = arcpy.ListTables()
for table in tableList:
    arcpy.Copy_management(table, os.path.join(destgdb, table))
```

Not only does this copy the tables, it also copies the feature classes as well as the relationship classes. This is not a problem for me because I need to copy all contents, not just tables. However, what does occur is a duplication of one of the tables, one of the feature classes, and one of the relationship classes. It also renames one of the relationship classes weirdly ("EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords__ATTACH__ATTACHREL" instead of "EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords__ATTACHREL")

[image]

My guess is that one of the tables, EnvtblTreeMaintenance participates in two relationship classes. It is the Destination for the TreeMaintenance relationship class and the Origin for the EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords__ATTACHREL relationship class.

This behaviour ***is not*** seen in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. When I copy the three tables manually in Catalog in Desktop, they copy across without problems. All feature classes and relationship classes also copy along with the tables. However, when I use the above python code in Desktop, everything seems to copy correctly, but I get the following error in the python console:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 2, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 4314, in
>   Copy     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000725: Output Data Element:
>   Dataset E:\Temp\dest.gdb\EnvtblTreeMaintenanceRecords__ATTACH already
>   exists.

**My question:** what is the best way to copy the data in the source geodatabase to the destination database in **ArcGIS Pro** without duplication of tables, feature classes and relationship classes?

Comment: Copy entire database, delete what you don't need.

Comment: The example I gave is not actually my ultimate workflow. In the end, I need to migrate multiple SDE databases into a single database with different database schemas for each original database.

Comment: Did you try using the `associated_data` parameter for the related tables and relationship classes?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall no I didn't. How would you suggest I use it for my purposes? I can't see how it will help. I won't know the names of the feature classes or tables in the final dataset. There are thousands of them.

Comment: Do a ListDatasets to find all datasets.  Then, similar to example 3, but don't put the Mexico featuredataset, see if it works with only the geodb paths in the `in_data` and `out_data`, then use your complete dataset list to build he `associated_data` parameter. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy.htm

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does using arcpy to do this in desktop work?  As I recall, manually copying stuff in the UI in desktop doesn't use geoprocessing behind the scenes (it uses IGeodbDataTransfer).

Comment: Yes, arcpy works in Desktop. However, it does result in an error which I mentioned in my post, however, the data is correct anyway.

Comment: Also, ListDatasets results in an empty list as there are no datasets, only tables, feature classes and relationship classes.

Comment: Oops, forgot Listdatasets lacks a featureclass as a type parameter ... so `ListFeatureclasses`, or `Walk`.

Comment: This sort of sounds like a bug (as you say it works in 10.6.1). I know some work was done to the Copy tool in Pro 2.x+ when copying items and their related components.

Comment: @Fezter Could you find a solution to this problem? I'm at the same thing right now!

Comment: @sandrooco Unfortunately, no. I abandoned ArcPro and implemented my solution in ArcMap using arcpy. Copied the feature classes first which copied the associated tables with hit.

Comment: How did you do it with arcpy? We're trying with arcpy too but sometimes not all of our data (from relations) gets copied...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with a different client now and don't have access to the code anymore. However, from memory, I copied just the feature classes across which brought any related tables. Then, I copied any tables which didn't get copied across. Hope that helps.